# How do I run a Tomcat-Spring/Struts 2-Quartz task outside of Tomcat?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2, quartz-scheduler

We have an application deployed on Tomcat 6.  It's built on Spring/Struts 2, and has several Quartz tasks scheduled.

We'd like to move some tasks away from Quartz and onto Linux's cron, doing the very least amount of coding as possible.  How do I run those Spring/Quartz tasks outside the Tomcat container and in a standalone Java application?

---

(UPDATE: Since someone wanted to know why we want to do this)

We wanted to move the scheduled tasks to their own Java applications because our Tomcat keeps dying on us.  There are no errors logged.  We suspect that this one huge Quartz task we have is the culprit, but whether it's because of a memory leak or our Tomcat seg-faulting due to being set-up incorrectly, we still don't know.

We wanted to isolate it by kicking it out of the Tomcat container, and see if Tomcat will still die intermittently.  However, since the application is already live (though in closed beta), we wanted to troubleshoot this with the least amount of coding work, while still keeping it running (coz, you know, "new code, new problems" -- FYI, we're already considering a rewrite/re-engineering, but "firefighting" is a more urgent concern right now).

Comment: Question: Why? And is it really worth it? I suggest you evaluate THAT first before moving on with the implementation...

Comment: @Nupul, I must apologize knowing why in this case does help.  Why not test on a different container (glassfish)? Have you put effort into using a profiler?  You have logging set up in your application? If it is not well implemented that would take a very short amount of time compared to re-engineering something that might only need a slight fix. You should be able to test more quickly by using a different container and seeing if the job dies there, if so you can just prune the project until you isolate it, this requires less work clearly (but still I would start with a profiler and logging).

Comment: using the same container on a different server and pruning would also be another strategy.

Comment: Something will be logged if you turn on debug or trace level logging, last things written would be of interest.

Comment: I would've liked to have a parallel deployment on a different server, but when we requested our infrastructure guys to give us an identical spec'd server, they said they no longer set-up "old" configurations -- our prod server is on CentOS 5.x, but they said they can only set-up CentOS 6.x nowadays. Don't ask me why, all I'd say is "corporate environment".

Comment: Logging is at debug level, but the live environment is just too noisy, since we increased the number of users for our closed beta. It will take some time digging through the logs, especially since we auto-restart Tomcat when it dies (can't afford not to).

Comment: Surprisingly, since I was tasked to investigate this problem, Tomcat hasn't died involuntarily on us! It's afraid of me! XD

Comment: I would take the second server they offered, it shouldn't matter what environment the container is running in.  I don't know how you are restarting tomcat but if it is in a script it would be worth modifying the script to copy and rename the logs to include date and timestamp of failure so you don't write over valuable data.  Funny how that is, about a watched computer never erring... Well if watched by someone who can fix it of course.

Comment: Yup, we took the second server anyway.  Funny thing is that, after we figured out how to run the tasks on their own (outside of Tomcat) and before we deployed the webapp with Quartz disabled, our Tomcat instance didn't ever die on us again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the simplest way to go about this is to create a standalone Java application that calls the bean method you're executing in Quartz:

```
import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.*;

public class SomeJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        MyBean myBean = (MyBean) ctx.getBean("myBean");
        myBean.someMethod();
    }

}
```

..then, running this in cron.

Meh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Quartz but I am familiar with stuts2 and cron.

Generally in linux you call separate processes with cron so I'd think it would be best to reduce the quartz jobs down into separate stand alone programs. Considering the Java EE nature of your project and the dependency on on aquiring services via spring I don't think this is a particularly attractive option.

A second route that I've seen with PHP but would work equally well with struts2, would be using lynx to call a specific url, which could trigger the job something like:

```
*/15 * * * * lynx -dump http://localhost/MyApp/MyAction
```

Which would call your action every 15 min (the dump option prevents lynx from entering interactive mode and just dumps output to stdout so the program will just run for a moment), which could then run your job.  You would then want to look at iptables (or similar) to restrict access to those services you would not want accessed externally. You can do this within struts2 as well by putting all these actions in a single package and making an interceptor to check that the requester is the local host.

I think this second method would require the least amount of change.

Comment: Nope, your second method won't do, as our intention is to move the task outside the Tomcat container. Thanks anyway. :)